# Cannot upload files over FTP - File not found

Tags: android, ftp

I wrote a simple app that gets all the pictures taken from camera and uploads them to the server through FTP. When I run the app, I get a really strange exception.

```
09-12 11:56:08.153: E/ThrottleService(149): problem during onPollAlarm: 
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
  /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Also the FTP client returns: `550 file not found`

The code for file upload:

```
    @Override
    public boolean storeFile(File file) {


        FileInputStream in = null;
        try {
            client.enterLocalActiveMode();
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            Log.d(TAG, "File exists: " + file.exists() + " File readabdle: " + file.canRead() + " File writable: " + file.canWrite()); 
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            boolean result = client.storeFile(file.getName(), in);
            in.close();
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                in.close();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that the log prints:

```
09-12 12:03:21.701: D/FTPClientApache(745): File exists: true File readabdle: 
true File writable: true
```

I tried also to enable FTP logs (Sorry for the length but I thought longer = better):

```
09-12 12:12:48.541: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPControlSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:12:48.542 : ListenOnAllInterfaces=true
09-12 12:12:48.562: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPControlSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:12:48.560 : ---> PORT 10,0,2,15,143,249
09-12 12:12:48.742: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPControlSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:12:48.742 : 200 Port command successful
09-12 12:12:48.742: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPControlSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:12:48.744 : ---> STOR test.jpg
09-12 12:12:48.791: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPControlSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:12:48.797 : 150 Opening data channel for file transfer.
09-12 12:12:48.802: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPActiveDataSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:12:48.799 : Calling accept()
09-12 12:13:48.822: I/System.out(798): ERROR [FTPClient] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:48.802 : Caught and rethrowing exception in getDataAfterInitGet() : null
09-12 12:13:48.822: I/System.out(798): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
09-12 12:13:48.822: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:108)
09-12 12:13:48.831: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:202)
09-12 12:13:48.831: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:127)
09-12 12:13:48.831: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.acceptConnection(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:185)
09-12 12:13:48.841: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.getOutputStream(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:201)
09-12 12:13:48.841: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getOutputStream(FTPClient.java:3318)
09-12 12:13:48.841: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putData(FTPClient.java:2877)
09-12 12:13:48.852: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putStream(FTPClient.java:2604)
09-12 12:13:48.852: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.put(FTPClient.java:2572)
09-12 12:13:48.852: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:857)
09-12 12:13:48.852: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:831)
09-12 12:13:48.861: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPClientEDT.storeFile(FTPClientEDT.java:62)
09-12 12:13:48.861: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.uploadFiles(FTPService.java:74)
09-12 12:13:48.861: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.onHandleIntent(FTPService.java:168)
09-12 12:13:48.861: I/System.out(798):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
09-12 12:13:48.861: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 12:13:48.861: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 12:13:48.871: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-12 12:13:48.871: I/System.out(798): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: accept failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
09-12 12:13:48.871: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
09-12 12:13:48.881: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
09-12 12:13:48.881: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
09-12 12:13:48.881: I/System.out(798):  ... 17 more
09-12 12:13:48.881: I/System.out(798): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
09-12 12:13:48.881: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:108)
09-12 12:13:48.881: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:202)
09-12 12:13:48.881: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:127)
09-12 12:13:48.892: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.acceptConnection(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:185)
09-12 12:13:48.892: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.getOutputStream(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:201)
09-12 12:13:48.902: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getOutputStream(FTPClient.java:3318)
09-12 12:13:48.902: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putData(FTPClient.java:2877)
09-12 12:13:48.902: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putStream(FTPClient.java:2604)
09-12 12:13:48.935: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.put(FTPClient.java:2572)
09-12 12:13:48.935: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:857)
09-12 12:13:48.935: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:831)
09-12 12:13:48.935: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPClientEDT.storeFile(FTPClientEDT.java:62)
09-12 12:13:48.935: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.uploadFiles(FTPService.java:74)
09-12 12:13:48.935: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.onHandleIntent(FTPService.java:168)
09-12 12:13:48.935: I/System.out(798):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
09-12 12:13:48.935: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 12:13:48.935: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 12:13:48.935: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-12 12:13:48.942: I/System.out(798): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: accept failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
09-12 12:13:48.942: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
09-12 12:13:48.942: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
09-12 12:13:48.942: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
09-12 12:13:48.942: I/System.out(798):  ... 17 more
09-12 12:13:48.942: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPActiveDataSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:48.947 : close() succeeded
09-12 12:13:48.982: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPClient] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:48.949 : Validate transfer on error after exception : null
09-12 12:13:48.982: I/System.out(798): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
09-12 12:13:48.982: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:108)
09-12 12:13:48.991: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:202)
09-12 12:13:48.991: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:127)
09-12 12:13:48.991: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.acceptConnection(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:185)
09-12 12:13:48.991: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.getOutputStream(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:201)
09-12 12:13:48.991: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getOutputStream(FTPClient.java:3318)
09-12 12:13:48.991: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putData(FTPClient.java:2877)
09-12 12:13:48.991: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putStream(FTPClient.java:2604)
09-12 12:13:48.991: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.put(FTPClient.java:2572)
09-12 12:13:49.001: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:857)
09-12 12:13:49.001: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:831)
09-12 12:13:49.001: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPClientEDT.storeFile(FTPClientEDT.java:62)
09-12 12:13:49.001: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.uploadFiles(FTPService.java:74)
09-12 12:13:49.014: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.onHandleIntent(FTPService.java:168)
09-12 12:13:49.014: I/System.out(798):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
09-12 12:13:49.014: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 12:13:49.014: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 12:13:49.014: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-12 12:13:49.014: I/System.out(798): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: accept failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
09-12 12:13:49.022: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
09-12 12:13:49.022: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
09-12 12:13:49.022: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
09-12 12:13:49.031: I/System.out(798):  ... 17 more
09-12 12:13:49.031: I/System.out(798): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
09-12 12:13:49.031: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:108)
09-12 12:13:49.031: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:202)
09-12 12:13:49.031: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:127)
09-12 12:13:49.041: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.acceptConnection(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:185)
09-12 12:13:49.041: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.getOutputStream(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:201)
09-12 12:13:49.041: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getOutputStream(FTPClient.java:3318)
09-12 12:13:49.041: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putData(FTPClient.java:2877)
09-12 12:13:49.041: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putStream(FTPClient.java:2604)
09-12 12:13:49.041: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.put(FTPClient.java:2572)
09-12 12:13:49.051: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:857)
09-12 12:13:49.081: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:831)
09-12 12:13:49.081: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPClientEDT.storeFile(FTPClientEDT.java:62)
09-12 12:13:49.081: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.uploadFiles(FTPService.java:74)
09-12 12:13:49.081: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.onHandleIntent(FTPService.java:168)
09-12 12:13:49.081: I/System.out(798):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
09-12 12:13:49.081: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 12:13:49.081: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 12:13:49.081: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-12 12:13:49.091: I/System.out(798): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: accept failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
09-12 12:13:49.091: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
09-12 12:13:49.091: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
09-12 12:13:49.091: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
09-12 12:13:49.102: I/System.out(798):  ... 17 more
09-12 12:13:49.131: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPControlSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:49.137 : 425 Can't open data connection.
09-12 12:13:49.131: I/System.out(798): INFO [FTPControlSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:49.139 : Expected reply codes = [225,226,250]
09-12 12:13:49.152: D/dalvikvm(798): GC_CONCURRENT freed 633K, 11% free 6269K/6983K, paused 15ms+32ms, total 98ms
09-12 12:13:49.152: I/System.out(798): WARN [FTPClient] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:49.141 : Validate transfer on error failed : Can't open data connection.
09-12 12:13:49.152: I/System.out(798): com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException: 425 Can't open data connection.
09-12 12:13:49.152: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.validateReply(FTPControlSocket.java:1235)
09-12 12:13:49.152: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.validateTransfer(FTPClient.java:2645)
09-12 12:13:49.152: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.validateTransferOnError(FTPClient.java:2664)
09-12 12:13:49.152: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putStream(FTPClient.java:2615)
09-12 12:13:49.152: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.put(FTPClient.java:2572)
09-12 12:13:49.152: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:857)
09-12 12:13:49.152: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:831)
09-12 12:13:49.152: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPClientEDT.storeFile(FTPClientEDT.java:62)
09-12 12:13:49.162: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.uploadFiles(FTPService.java:74)
09-12 12:13:49.162: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.onHandleIntent(FTPService.java:168)
09-12 12:13:49.162: I/System.out(798):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
09-12 12:13:49.162: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 12:13:49.162: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 12:13:49.162: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-12 12:13:49.162: I/System.out(798): com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException: 425 Can't open data connection.
09-12 12:13:49.162: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.validateReply(FTPControlSocket.java:1235)
09-12 12:13:49.162: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.validateTransfer(FTPClient.java:2645)
09-12 12:13:49.171: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.validateTransferOnError(FTPClient.java:2664)
09-12 12:13:49.171: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putStream(FTPClient.java:2615)
09-12 12:13:49.171: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.put(FTPClient.java:2572)
09-12 12:13:49.171: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:857)
09-12 12:13:49.171: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:831)
09-12 12:13:49.171: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPClientEDT.storeFile(FTPClientEDT.java:62)
09-12 12:13:49.171: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.uploadFiles(FTPService.java:74)
09-12 12:13:49.182: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.onHandleIntent(FTPService.java:168)
09-12 12:13:49.182: I/System.out(798):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
09-12 12:13:49.182: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 12:13:49.182: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 12:13:49.182: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-12 12:13:49.182: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPClient] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:49.188 : Sleeping for 5000 ms prior to retry
09-12 12:13:54.201: I/System.out(798): ERROR [FTPClient] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:54.194 : Transfer error on attempt #2 retrying:  : null
09-12 12:13:54.201: I/System.out(798): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
09-12 12:13:54.211: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:108)
09-12 12:13:54.211: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:202)
09-12 12:13:54.211: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:127)
09-12 12:13:54.211: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.acceptConnection(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:185)
09-12 12:13:54.221: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.getOutputStream(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:201)
09-12 12:13:54.221: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getOutputStream(FTPClient.java:3318)
09-12 12:13:54.221: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putData(FTPClient.java:2877)
09-12 12:13:54.232: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putStream(FTPClient.java:2604)
09-12 12:13:54.232: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.put(FTPClient.java:2572)
09-12 12:13:54.232: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:857)
09-12 12:13:54.241: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:831)
09-12 12:13:54.241: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPClientEDT.storeFile(FTPClientEDT.java:62)
09-12 12:13:54.241: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.uploadFiles(FTPService.java:74)
09-12 12:13:54.251: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.onHandleIntent(FTPService.java:168)
09-12 12:13:54.251: I/System.out(798):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
09-12 12:13:54.251: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 12:13:54.251: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 12:13:54.251: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-12 12:13:54.251: I/System.out(798): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: accept failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  ... 17 more
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:108)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:202)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:127)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.acceptConnection(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:185)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.internal.FTPActiveDataSocket.getOutputStream(FTPActiveDataSocket.java:201)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getOutputStream(FTPClient.java:3318)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putData(FTPClient.java:2877)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putStream(FTPClient.java:2604)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.put(FTPClient.java:2572)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:857)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.uploadFile(FileTransferClient.java:831)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPClientEDT.storeFile(FTPClientEDT.java:62)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.uploadFiles(FTPService.java:74)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at service.FTPService.onHandleIntent(FTPService.java:168)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 12:13:54.261: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 12:13:54.272: I/System.out(798):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-12 12:13:54.272: I/System.out(798): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: accept failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
09-12 12:13:54.272: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
09-12 12:13:54.272: I/System.out(798):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
09-12 12:13:54.282: I/System.out(798):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
09-12 12:13:54.282: I/System.out(798):  ... 17 more
09-12 12:13:54.291: I/System.out(798): INFO [FTPClient] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:54.285 : Resume=true
09-12 12:13:54.291: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPClient] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:54.293 : Attempt #3
****09-12 12:13:54.291: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPControlSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:54.298 : ---> SIZE test.jpg
09-12 12:13:54.341: I/System.out(798): DEBUG [FTPControlSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:54.346 : 550 File not found
09-12 12:13:54.341: I/System.out(798): INFO [FTPControlSocket] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:54.349 : Expected reply code = [213]
09-12 12:13:54.352: I/System.out(798): WARN [FTPClient] 12 Sep 2014 12:13:54.351 : SIZE failed 'test.jpg' - resume will not be used (File not found)****
```

I tried both edtFTPj/Free and Apache's commons library. I have an abstract class that has three methods - connect, storeFile and disconnect so I can easily switch between those two libraries without changing code.

Comment: check if `in` is not `null`

Comment: Which ftp client do you use?

Comment: `@Override
    public boolean storeFile(File file)` What are you overriding? Can you upload one file to begin with?

Comment: @greenapps I updated the question, you can see answers to your questions in the bottom

Comment: You did answer none of my questions. And you have a `SocketTimeoutException`.

Comment: I tried both edtFTPj/Free and Apache's commons library (FTPClients). I have an abstract class that has three methods - connect, storeFile(overriden) and disconnect so I can easily switch between those two libraries without changing code. (I do not override any of the FTP clients methods). The timeout exception is related to the file that for some reason cannot be found I guess

Comment: `The timeout exception is related to the file that for some reason cannot be found.`. No. Such an exception occurs when the client cannot connect to the server. You have a connection problem. Maybe the original connection gets established. But for transfers other channels (ports) are used. There something goes wrong. How is your network setup? Unusual?